# symfony 2 sonataAdminBundle override template

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

how can we override sonata bundle layout for a single Admin class
like i have created 3 Admin Class userAdmin, productAdmin, ticketAdmin
now i want to override ticketAdmin edit action and edit template and add some extra code there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to create an extra controller you can use this method mentioned in the docs:

[Admin's documentation - Reference - Templates  (master) - 20.6. Configuring templates](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates)

```
services:
sonata.admin.post:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Admin\PostAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Post" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post
        - ~
    calls:
        - [ setTemplate, [edit, AcmeDemoBundle:PostAdmin:edit.html.twig]]
```

And put your template in *Resources/views/PostAdmin/edit.html.twig*. Just copy the original template from the SonataAdmin Bundle and start overriding.

Blogged at: [Override list view twig template in SonataAdminBundle – webDEVILopers Blog](http://blog.webdevilopers.net/override-list-view-twig-template-in-sonataadminbundle/)

Answer (score 14):

You can use :

**Controller :**

[custom action in SonataAdminBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740303/custom-action-in-sonataadminbundle)

**Template :**

```
// in your admin class
public function getTemplate($name)
{
    switch ($name) {
        case 'edit':
            return 'AcmeMyBundle::my-custom-edit.html.twig';
            break;
        default:
            return parent::getTemplate($name);
            break;
    }
}
```