# custom action in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

On this [page](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/routing.html#create-a-route) I found how to add route for my custom action.

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    $collection->add('ispremium', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/ispremium'); 
}
```

After that I add custom action in my Admin class:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')
        ->add('code', null, array('label' => 'Code'))
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array( 
            'actions' => array(  
                'ispremium' => array(
                    'template' => 'AppMyBundleBundle:Admin:ispremium.html.twig'
                )
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

It generated  url like this:

```
/app_dev.php/admin/mobispot/discodes/discode/300876/ispremium
```

My template for this link:

```
<a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('ispremium', object) }}">Link</a>
```

I dont' know how to solve this problems:

1. How to define custom controller for that route pass?
   Now I have an error:

   Method "Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::ispremiumAction" does not exist.
2. Can I change generated url with generateUrl method?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you are creating service for `EntityAdmin` class the third argument is the controller name. You can create a class that extends `CRUDController` and set it in service. e.g

The controller,

```
//Vendor\YourBundle\Controller\EntityAdminController.php

class EntityAdminController extends CRUDController
{
    public function ispremiumAction()
    {
        //process
    }
}
```

In `services.yml`,

```
entity.admin.service:
  class: FQCN\Of\EntityAdmin
  tags:
    - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: your_group, label: Label }
  arguments: [null, FQCN\Of\Entity, VendorYourBundle:EntityAdmin]
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! P.S. I'm noob in symfony 2.0 and just found, that I can also set _controller in $collection->add method