# How add a delete checkbox in a form in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox

I want to add a delete checkbox to a form.

I have a collection of USER, and I want a checkbox aside each of them so I can (Administrator) delete any user.

But when I integrate a delete checkbox in the form

```
 ->add('delete','checkbox',array('label'=>'delete','required'=>false,));
```

the following message is triggered in symfony:

> "Neither the property "delete" nor one of the methods "getDelete()", "isDelete()", "hasDelete()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Site\BlogBundle\Entity\User".

Should I add a property delete and a getDelete(), so that I can use it?

What is the proper way to do it?

Please take into account in you answer that this is a collection. I want the delete option (via a checkbox) to be integrated for each item (of the collection).

Comment: Define what you mean when you say "delete user". What would that actually *do*?

Comment: Do you mean to add a custom action? This topic might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740303/custom-action-in-sonataadminbundle

Answer (score 1):

By default, every form builder item is mapped to the entity that it belongs to. This is the `mapped` attribute. Simply set this attribute to `false`:

```
->add('delete', 'checkbox', array(
    'label' => 'delete',
    'required' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
));
```

Then handle the element in your controller:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$deleteChecked = $form->get('delete')->getData();
// do stuff with $deleteChecked
```

For a collection I'd imagine something like this:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
foreach ($form->get('collection_name') as $item) {
    $deleteChecked = $item->get('delete')->getData();
    // do stuff with $deleteChecked
}
```

would work, however how to actually handle the deletion is out of my depth as it goes against the grain of how Symfony collections handle deletions.

**HOWEVER**, why are you creating your own `delete` checkbox when the collection Form Type has [a delete mechanism built into it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-delete)? If you [follow these steps](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed), you should be able to delete items with DOM manipulation.

You could have the checkbox cause a DOM element deletion *right before form submission* such as an `onSubmit` action or bind, that way the data still shows right before deletion.

Comment: Thks sjagr, I used the mapped false option as I do not want to visually delete the user from the view page before it is submited. I have one more question. **How do I get the value of Delete now? As the form contains a collection and for each collection I have a delete checkbox... form->get('delete')->getData() won't be working**

Comment: this is not working, I already tried and it trigger the following error msg: **Error: Call to a member function get() on array **

Answer (score 1):

Yes if this form is mapped with you User entity then you have to create a property or get method to do so. Otherwise you have to make the delete field as mapped false.